# I can't do multiple os.system() commands. What am I missing?

Tags: python, os.system

```
def separateSegments():
    sound_file = pydub.AudioSegment.from_wav("SSTV-Complete-Transmission.wav")
    sound_file_Value = np.array(sound_file.get_array_of_samples())
    # milliseconds in the sound track
    # * 4.88
    ranges = [(0,1805600),(1805600,3625800),(3625800,5494800),(5494800,7300400),(7300400,9106000)]

    #print(str(ranges))

    for x, y in ranges:
        new_file=sound_file_Value[x : y]
        song = pydub.AudioSegment(new_file.tobytes(), frame_rate=sound_file.frame_rate,sample_width=sound_file.sample_width,channels=1)
        song.export("AMEA_Transmission_" + str(x) + "-" + str(y) +".wav", format="wav")

def processSegments():
    os.system('''cmd /k "sstv -d AMEA_Transmission_0-1805600.wav -o AMEA_Data_Result_0-1805600.png"''')
    jeff = 1
    os.system('''cmd /k "sstv -d AMEA_Transmission_1805600-3625800.wav -o AMEA_Data_Result_1805600-3625800.png"''')
```

I'm trying to run multiple os.system commands that uses a command prompt command from https://github.com/colaclanth/sstv. For whatever reason, it only runs the first and ignores the second. Is there a way for it to run multiple commands?

Comment: Can’t you `os.system("sstv -d AMEA_Transmission_0-1805600.wav -o AMEA_Data_Result_0-1805600.png")` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmd /k ...` means *"run the following command, then remain open"*. You're running the first `os.system` call, but since `cmd` does not terminate, the call never returns, and the program doesn't advance to the next line.

You probably want the `/c` option instead of `/k`. That means *"run the following command, then terminate"*.